# Does ag-grid support live updates in Server-Side row model?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am picking a grid to use in a React app to peer into very large data sets, with filtering, grouping, sorting capabilities. So, this has to be a virtual grid. According to this article (https://www.crankuptheamps.com//blog/posts/2020/01/23/grid-comparison-2/#) ag-Grid is phenomenal. Server-Side Row Model seems to support our "data massaging" requirements. However, I cannot find a confirmation whether in this mode ag-Grid supports live updates from server side (data push).
Could you please point me in the right direction? If you have a doc link or a sample it would be even better.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

[ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) has a different row model for this: [Viewport row model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-viewport/)

> A Viewport is a row model that allows showing a 'window' of data in your client. Typically all the data will reside on the server and the server will know what data is displayed in the client. This is again useful for the server to push changes out to the client as it knows what data is currently displayed.

Comment: thank you for your response. I've found the confirmation of "virtuality" for Viewport, but according to the supported feature list it does not support grouping (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-models/), which is a must.